# String literals in ASP.NET Core MVC tag helper arguments

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

Razor allows arguments to ASP.NET Core MVC tag helpers to be written as inline C# expressions within the corresponding attribute declaration. However, since HTML attributes are delimited by quotation marks, what's the syntax if such an expression should itself contain a quotation mark?

Here's a sample from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring:

```
<website-information info="new WebsiteContext {
    Version = new Version(1, 3),
    CopyrightYear = 1638,
    Approved = true,
    TagsToShow = 131 }" />
```

What would this look like if one of the `WebsiteContext` properties were to take a string literal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since my original answers was flawed, here is an approach that will work that I tested on code similar to yours:

If the CopyrightYear is a string what you can do is use single quotes for the outer quotes and use double quotes for the strings like so:

```
 <website-information info='new WebsiteContext {
                                Version = new Version(1, 3),
                                CopyrightYear = "1638",
                                Approved = true,
                                TagsToShow = 131 }' />
```

Comment: With your approach and ASP.NET Core MVC 1.1, I'm getting this: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to process this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. [... ] Invalid expression term '' [...] CopyrightYear = \"1638\", [...] Unexpected character '\'

Comment: It may be because CopyrightYear  in your WebsiteContext object is currently of type int.  Change it to type string and see.  Or try the \" escape technique with some other property that is of type string.

Comment: That's not it, I of course changed the type to string first. (And I also tried it with another string property.) Does this actually work for you? And if yes, what ASP.NET Core version are you using? Could this be a 2.0 feature?

Comment: My bad, I assumed escaping the quotes would work because it's an approach that works in many situations but alas it does not work in this case so I have provided an alternative approach above that I have tested and does work for this situation.

Comment: It's a viable workaround as long as I don't need to mix string and char literals (or use an apostrophe within the string literal, I guess), but I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if there are alternative ideas.

Comment: Accepting the answer on the assumption there is actually no way of escaping the quotation marks, so a workaround must be used.

Answer (score 8):

If you wrap the `new` expression in `@(...)` it will all be treated as C# code so you won't have a problem.

Like this:

```
<website-information info="@(new WebsiteContext {
                            Version = new Version(1, 3),
                            CopyrightYear = "1638",
                            Approved = true,
                            TagsToShow = 131 })" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, because it works with any string literal and even any C# code (as mentioned in the answer), even if it contains multiple strings or strings that contains a single quotation mark. Works great when migrating legacy code with `@Html.Partial` to the `<partial>` tag helper using regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative workaround to the one described in Ron C's answer, one could also put the `WebSiteContext` construction code into a separate Razor code block, storing the result in a variable.

```
@{
var context = new WebsiteContext {
        Version = new Version(1, 3),
        CopyrightYear = "1638",
        Approved = true,
        TagsToShow = 131 };
}

<website-information info="@context" />
```